# The max value within a foreach loop php

Tags: php, foreach, max

Hope you are doing well, I am sorry if my question is a bit silly, but I have spent hours trying to find a solution to my problem but without any success, can somebody help me?

I am trying to find the max value within my foreach loop, and when I try to use the `max()` function, it doesn't show any result at all ...

```php
foreach ($decode2 as $value) {
    $maak = max($value->price_change_percentage_24h);
}

echo $maak;
```

and when I do the simple test with :

```php
foreach ($decode2 as $value) {    
    echo $value->price_change_percentage_24h;   
}
```

I can see all my data ...

Please any help would be very appreciated ! :)

Comment: Is `$value->price_change_percentage_24h` an array?

Comment: Indeed it is ! ;)

Comment: Can you do a `print_r($value->price_change_percentage_24h)` and show us the output please

Comment: I doubt very much that `$value->price_change_percentage_24h` is an array. `$value` is an object, and `price_change_percentage_24h` looks like a value. Assuming your `$decode2` is decoded from JSON, decode to an array instead, and then simply do `max(array_column($decode2, 'price_change_percentage_24h'));`.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? That's so little code that dumping the values could help, while using XDebug would be even more helpful. Also, why do you override `$maak` in each iteration of your loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass several arguments to the `max` function, so that it returns the maximum value.

You should probably do something like this:

```
<?php 

foreach ($decode2 as $value) {
    $maak = max($maak, $value->price_change_percentage_24h);   
}

echo $maak;

?>
```

Have a look here if you have any doubts:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.max.php

This includes some examples as well

Comment: Wow Thank you Grégoire! It worked just fine, I can't believe how quick you helped me, it is very much appreciated, have an awesome day !

Comment: _"If the first and only parameter is an array, max() returns the highest value in that array."_ It works just fine with one value. Where does `$maak` come from, as far as being the first argument here? As far as I can tell it isn't even defined, and should produce a warning instead of making this work. If there is an initial value for `$maak`, then this loop will compare over and over two values, and yes it will end up with the maximum, but is far from the optimal way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the `$value->price_change_percentage_24h` value into another array and then use `max()` function.

```
$temp = array();
foreach ($decode2 as $value) {
    array_push($temp, $value->price_change_percentage_24h);
}

$maak = max($temp);
echo $maak;
```

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the array function

```
foreach ($decode2 as $value) {
    $maak = max(array($value['price_change_percentage_24h']));
}

echo $maak;
```

Include the array() function To avoid the below error

*PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning Message: max(): When only one parameter is given, it must be an array*

Comment: Why? If `$value->price_change_percentage_24h` contains an array, what would be the benefit?

Comment: You are able to avoid this error (A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: max(): When only one parameter is given, it must be an array)

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it. What makes you think that this error occurs?